# Integrate JQuery Isotope in Product Listing

Tags: product-list, sorting

How can I integrate jQuery isotope in my product listing page ?

When user sorts by `Position / Name / Price`, instead of reloading the page, I need to sort the products just like its happening in [isotope jquery](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Pls Guide.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Integrated the isotope plugin, but no success as Magento changes the URL when sorted ? Do I need to fetch all records ?